# Change displayed flash file by clicking a button

Tags: flash

I'm on Windows Vista and IE7.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. I have two flash files: `page1.swf` and `page2.swf`. They are just page from a magazine.
2. Display `page1.swf`
3. Have a button that says "Change page"
4. When I click the button; display `page2.swf` instead of `page1.swf` (only `page2.swf`, not both pages)
   That's it.

If anyone can give me a script to do that I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

this function changes the flash embedded in the element:

```
function setFlashSrc(newSrc)    
    {          
        var flash='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="210" HEIGHT="210">';          
        flash+='<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="'+newSrc+'"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>';          
        flash+='<EMBED SRC="'+newSrc+'" QUALITY=high PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" ';          
        flash+='TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" WIDTH="210" HEIGHT="210">';          
        flash+='</EMBED>';          
        flash+='</OBJECT>';          
        document.getElementById("urelement").innerHTML=flash;    
        }
```

replace the flash attributes as you need.

Answer (score 0):

For managing SWF objects in your pages, using JavaScript I recommend you to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Check this question also: [How to use javascript to swap swf in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291647/how-to-use-javascript-to-swap-swf-in-html)